# Неправильная ширина третьего уровня выпадающего меню

Tags: html, css, css3, menu

Есть трехуровневое выпадающее меню. Первый и второй уровни корректно раздвигаются по ширине содержимого внутри, а вот третий никак не хочет "понимать" ширину содержимого.

В чем ошибка?

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #333;
}

.header-nav > ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    /*position: relative;*/
}

.header-nav li:hover {
    background: #008dd2;
}

.header-nav a {
    color: #f4f4f4;
    font-family:'ProximaNovaBold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.drop{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: auto;
}

.drop li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.header-nav li:hover .drop {
    display: block;
}

.drop2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    display: none;
    background: #333;
}

.drop li:hover .drop2 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Ссылка 2 большая</a>
            <ul class="drop">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
                    <ul class="drop2">
                        <li><a href="#">Подссылка 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подссылка 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подссылка 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подссылка 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2 большая ссылка</a>
                    <ul class="drop2">
                        <li><a href="#">Подссылка 1 большая</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подссылка 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подссылка 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подссылка 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/falkone/or5d2ya8/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Увеличьте ширину блока подссылок и добавьте в стиль `drop2` - `white-space:nowrap;`

**UPD**
Или можно параметр `width` у `drop2` совсем убрать, тогда ширина автоматом будет подбираться.

Comment: Вот как раз вариант с удалением фиксированной ширины звучит лучше всего (конечно, вместе с `white-space: nowrap`). [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/or5d2ya8/2/).

Comment: Фиксированную ширину забыл убрать действительно. `white-space: nowrap` решает всю проблему. Спасибо большое!